# Cloudant: Check if array is empty

Tags: cloudant

I've this entry:

```
 "entries": {
   "members": {
      "person": [
        {
         "name": "Jane Doe",
        }
  ]}}
```

Now I would like to check if the persons array is empty or has some entries.

I already tried with $exists:

```
  "selector": {
    "entries": {
     "members": {
        "person": {
           "name": {
              "$exists": true
           }
        }
     }
  }
 }
}
```

And with $neq

```
"selector": {
    "entries": {
     "members": {
        "person": {
           "name": {
              "$neq": ""
           }
        }
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Both approaches don't work..any tips?

Answer (score 0):

you may want try using the [`$size` operator](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#the-size-operator). for example,

```
"selector": {
  "entries": {
    "members": {
      "person": {
        "$size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with:

```
"entries.members.person": {
     "$elemMatch": {
        "name": {
           "$exists": true
        }
     }
  }
```